# jQuery search function not running in Wordpress but running locally (fiddle)

Tags: jquery, javascript

as the title suggests, I am running into this annoying issue:

The search is not working in wordpress but it is working in the fiddle and locally.

The sorting is working in wordpress.

I have the jquery load script in wordpress post body:

https://jsfiddle.net/ncxv16eL/

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your scripts included in the post?

Comment: yes because the search script and the sort script are 1 file and the sorting works.

Answer (score 0):

I was loading jQuery after loading script like this:

```
<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It needs to be jQuery on top.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://wp_enqueue_script) method to handle this, you can set dependencies that will address this exact issue by making sure that jQuery is loaded before your script.

Also, WordPress ships with jQuery - is there a reason your loading an external copy?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include jquery manually. Wordpress is shipped with jquery. You should take a look at [wp_enqueue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to get familiar with scripts inclusion in your site.